# Underbrace in equation in align environment

Tags: align, braces

In my code below, I wanted to add another underbrace under the "B" underbrace in the beginning of the second equation with z.  The second underbrace should cover from the [x,y] to just before the "=" sign. Like this:

[image]

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix} & = \begin{bmatrix}
-(L_{1} + r_{3v})\sin\theta_{1} + r_{2v}\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1} & \cos\theta_{1}\\
(L_{1} + r_{3v})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2v}\sin\theta_{1} & -\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta\theta_{1}\\
\delta r_{2} \\
\delta r_{3}
\end{bmatrix} +  \nonumber\\
& \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
(L_{1} + r_{3v})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2v}\sin\theta_{1} \\
(L_{1} + r_{3v})\sin\theta_{1} - r_{2v}\cos\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}\\[2ex]
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix} & -
{\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
(L_{1} + r_{3v})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2v}\sin\theta_{1} \\
(L_{1} + r_{3v})\sin\theta_{1} - r_{2v}\cos\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}}_B} = \nonumber\\
& \qquad\qquad{\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
-(L_{1} + r_{3v})\sin\theta_{1} + r_{2v}\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1} & \cos\theta_{1}\\
(L_{1} + r_{3v})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2v}\sin\theta_{1} & -\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}}_{H}}
{\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\delta\theta_{1}\\
\delta r_{2} \\
\delta r_{3}
\end{bmatrix}}_{\bf{u}}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: ,@Joe Your question is not clear, what do you mean by _get this underbrace in the second equation_?

Comment: Sorry for such an initial vague question.  I have added some more comments to clear up the uncertainty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the position of `&` and add a further level of `\underbrace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
-(L_{1} + r_{3v})\sin\theta_{1} + r_{2v}\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1} & \cos\theta_{1}\\
(L_{1} + r_{3v})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2v}\sin\theta_{1} & -\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta\theta_{1}\\
\delta r_{2} \\
\delta r_{3}
\end{bmatrix} +  \nonumber\\
& \hspace{14em}
\begin{bmatrix}
(L_{1} + r_{3v})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2v}\sin\theta_{1} \\
(L_{1} + r_{3v})\sin\theta_{1} - r_{2v}\cos\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}\\[2ex]
&{\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix} \mathrel{-}% just for getting alignment
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
(L_{1} + r_{3v})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2v}\sin\theta_{1} \\
(L_{1} + r_{3v})\sin\theta_{1} - r_{2v}\cos\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}}_B}_{\mathbf{z}}} = \nonumber\\
& \hspace{4em}
{\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
-(L_{1} + r_{3v})\sin\theta_{1} + r_{2v}\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1} & \cos\theta_{1}\\
(L_{1} + r_{3v})\cos\theta_{1} + r_{2v}\sin\theta_{1} & -\cos\theta_{1} & \sin\theta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}}_{H}}
{\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\delta\theta_{1}\\
\delta r_{2} \\
\delta r_{3}
\end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf{u}}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Please, avoid `\bf`: the correct syntax is `\mathbf{u}`, not `{\bf{u}}`. Instead of a bunch of `\qquad`, use `\hspace`, it's easier.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Working from my initial code, I wanted to add another underbrace, this time with a "z" under the original "B" underbrace. I have edited my original post to hopefully make it a little less vague.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Joe Your wish is my command! `;-)`

Comment: Superstar...superstar!